# ChromeDriverManager Could not reach host, but only on home network

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium to automate some work related report downloads on a Linux distribution (using Linux because I want to use Airflow, but can't use Docker).

When I am in the office the code runs exactly as expected, but when I am working from home I get an error saying it could not reach host.

Errors:

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='googlechromelabs.github.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /chrome-for-testing/latest-patch-versions-per-build.json (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2932071720>: Failed to resolve 'googlechromelabs.github.io' ([Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution)"))`

`"requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: Could not reach host. Are you offline?"`

Versions:

- Python 3.10.12
- Selenium 4.14.0
- webdriver-manager 4.0.1

Code:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

prefs = {
   "download.default_directory": download_path,
   "savefile.default_directory": download_path
}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

For clarity the download_path is just where the reports download too.

This is my first time setting something like this up for work, but my assumption is it has to do with the VPN connection while at home.

I'm at a loss for what all to try since I have it working, but it just doesn't work on my home network.

Comment: Can you `ping googlechromelabs.github.io`?

Comment: Not working, just get this response.

`ping: googlechromelabs.github.io: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Same thing trying to ping even generic websites like google.com

Comment: So, you have a network problem.  You do not have a programming problem, probably related to routing.  You need to work with your IT department.

Comment: I do want to thank you @Tim Roberts, the additional minor troubleshooting gave me another lead to search off of to better search for solutions.


For anyone that finds this it's apparently a common problem. Following these steps helped fix it, but needed to restart my entire system.

https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/troubleshooting-temporary-failure-name-resolution-error-linux